# How to add columns to a dataframe without cutting off first row entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
Alice,23
Bob,45
Chuck,9
Daren,25
Elisa,16
```

When I read it using pandas with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
```

It becomes a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Alice   23
0     Bob   45
1   Chuck    9
2   Daren   25
3   Elisa   16
```

Then, when I want to rename the columns, i.e.

```
df.columns = ['name', 'age']
```

I get this:

```
     name  age
0     Bob   45
1   Chuck    9
2   Daren   25
3   Elisa   16
```

And as such, Alice of 23 years old is nowhere to be seen. What's the cleanest way to solve this issue? How to preserve the first data entry? Thanks!

Comment: `Alice` and `23` are the column names because they are the first row in the csv file. Add `header=None` when you read the file

Answer (score 0):

use
this will give the dataset without default headers.

```
df = pd.read_csv=('my_csv.csv',header=None)
```

for new headers you can use below command.

```
df.columns = ['name','age']
```